# OData Function Encountered invalid type cast. Type is not assignable from '<null>'

Tags: java, dynamics-crm, odata, microsoft-dynamics

**Context**

What's the proper syntax for [RetrieveAttributeChangeHistory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/retrieveattributechangehistory?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) parameters?

Trying [RetrieveAttributeChangeHistory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/audit?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9#operations) from the Dynamics 365 [audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/audi) entity. I need some help forming the proper syntax for the OData function parameters. Right now my current query introduces a namespace issues. The first parameter requies a `crmbaseentity` type so I am providing the account entity with the full namespace and still running into errors.

```
https://msott.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/RetrieveAttributeChangeHistory(Target=Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account, AttributeLogicalName='numberofemployees', PagingInfo=null)/audits(a1618561-ac5c-e911-b49e-0003ffd79e21)
```

**Error**

> Encountered invalid type cast. 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account' is not assignable from null

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "0x8006088a",
        "message": "Encountered invalid type cast. 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account' is not assignable from '<null>'.",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "Encountered invalid type cast. 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account' is not assignable from '<null>'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.OData.ODataException",
            "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.UriEdmHelpers.CheckRelatedTo(IEdmType parentType, IEdmType childType)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.DottedIdentifierBinder.BindDottedIdentifier(DottedIdentifierToken dottedIdentifierToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.FunctionCallBinder.BindSegmentParameters(ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration, IEdmOperation functionOrOpertion, ICollection`1 segmentParameterTokens)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataPathParser.TryBindingParametersAndMatchingOperationImport(String identifier, String parenthesisExpression, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration, ICollection`1& boundParameters, IEdmOperationImport& matchingFunctionImport)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataPathParser.TryCreateSegmentForOperationImport(String identifier, String parenthesisExpression)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataPathParser.CreateFirstSegment(String segmentText)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataPathParser.ParsePath(ICollection`1 segments)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataPathFactory.BindPath(ICollection`1 segments, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataUriParser.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.Parse(String serviceRoot, String odataPath, IServiceProvider requestContainer, Boolean template)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.Parse(String serviceRoot, String odataPath, IServiceProvider requestContainer)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ODataV4.Routing.CrmODataPathHandler.Parse(String serviceRoot, String odataPath, IServiceProvider requestContainer)"
        }
    }
}
```